# Fastest way to extract frames using ffmpeg?

Tags: video, ffmpeg

Hi I need to extract frames from videos using ffmpeg.. Is there a faster way to do it than this:

```
ffmpeg -i file.mpg -r 1/1 $filename%03d.jpg
```

?

Comment: ^ updated url: https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Seeking

Comment: If you have CPU cycles to spare, you can extract from multiple videos in parallel: `parallel -i {} -r 1/1 {.}-%03d.bmp ::: *mpg`

Answer (score 251, accepted):

If the JPEG encoding step is too performance intensive, you could always store the frames uncompressed as BMP images:

```
ffmpeg -i file.mpg -r 1/1 $filename%03d.bmp
```

This also has the advantage of not incurring more quality loss through quantization by transcoding to JPEG. (PNG is also lossless but tends to take much longer than JPEG to encode.)

Comment: this seems to output one more frame that there is in the video (number I can get with the showinfo filter or ffprobe)

Comment: This results in *a lot* of frame dropping on my machine. Can I tell ffmpeg to render everything?

Comment: @Evi1M4chine just remove the -r parameter this will extract all frames

Comment: I'd like to add that while JPEG isn't really hard on the CPU, uncompressed Bitmaps is really really hard on the storage, so I doubt you'll get higher throughput with BMP compared to JPEG.

Comment: To extract all frames: `ffmpeg -r 1 file.mp4 -r 1 "$filename%03d.png"`

Comment: You mean `ffmpeg -r 1 -i file.mp4 -r 1 "$filename%03d.png`, right? (you were missing the `-i`)

Comment: Is it possible to output a frame, or every frame into a local variable (In Node or Python for example)?

Comment: Trying this on a Mac, it works only if removing the `1/1` argument.  With the `1/1` it fails, saying `Unable to find a suitable output format for '1/1'
1/1: Invalid argument`

Answer (score 98):

Came across this question, so here's a quick comparison. Compare these two different ways to extract one frame per minute from a video 38m07s long:

```
time ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -filter:v fps=fps=1/60 ffmpeg_%0d.bmp
```

1m36.029s

This takes long because ffmpeg parses the entire video file to get the desired frames.

```
time for i in {0..39} ; do ffmpeg -accurate_seek -ss `echo $i*60.0 | bc` -i input.mp4   -frames:v 1 period_down_$i.bmp ; done
```

0m4.689s

This is about 20 times faster. We use fast seeking to go to the desired time index and extract a frame, then call ffmpeg several times for every time index. Note that `-accurate_seek` [is the default](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Main-options)
, and make sure you add `-ss` before the input video `-i` option.

Note that it's better to use `-filter:v -fps=fps=...` instead of `-r` as [the latter may be inaccurate.](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Create%20a%20thumbnail%20image%20every%20X%20seconds%20of%20the%20video) Although [the ticket is marked as fixed](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/1578), I still did experience some issues, so better play it safe.

Comment: Feb 2016: as of ffmpeg 2.1, the accurate seek option is now default - https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Seeking

Comment: `bc` is not a native Ubuntu package, instead one can use bash: `let "i = $i * 60"`. BTW - excellent idea

Comment: Good tip adding `-ss` before `-i`. Otherwise, the whole video will be decoded and the unrequired frames will be discarded

Comment: Since this is top of google, I'd like to note that in 2018 this is still an approach that yields dividends. The best result seems to be running one `ffmpeg` per core of your host - which (for bmp) yields near-linear improvements in speed (until you hit some other bottleneck, like disk).

Comment: Could you explain why the second method be faster than the first method much more? They may also do the same work: locate the frame. The first method locate a frame at 10-frame intervals, and the second method locate a specified frame in many times.

Comment: hi I'm trying to get the frame every 10 seconds, I changed the 60.0 to 10.0 but it still only retrieve 46 images in a 45min video. Could someone help please?

Comment: hi @giladmayani new to Linux, could you please put the full command here? thanks

Comment: @Franva should be smt like this (UNTESTED): `-ss \`let "j = $i * 60" && echo $j\``

Comment: I'm try to use ``time for i in {3600..7680} ; do ffmpeg -accurate_seek -ss `echo $i*60.0 | bc` -i input.mp4 -frames:v 1 $filename%03d.png ; done`` and ffmpeg complains about: `Output file is empty, nothing was encoded (check -ss / -t / -frames parameters if used)`

Comment: @Domi.Zhang Because -ss skips to that point without decoding any frames.  The other option decodes every frame.

Comment: Doing this in Windows CMD was 4x slower for me. python subprocess.run `f'FOR /L %G IN (1000, 200, {video_duration}) DO ffmpeg -ss %Gms -i {video_path} -frames:v 1 {frames_dir}%G.jpg"'`

Answer (score 59):

This is simpler than all the other commands so far:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 '%04d.png'
```

Change `04` to however many digits you need to hold all frames. Make sure to always have a `0` before the number so output frame names are zero-padded.

Comment: No need for `-pix_fmt rgba`. The PNG encoder will automatically choose the appropriate pixel format.

Comment: @llogan thanks, removed it with an edit. Got a source for that though?

Comment: You can view a list of supported pixel formats for the PNG encoder with `ffmpeg -h encoder=png`. See [`avcodec_find_best_pix_fmt_of_list` documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/group__lavc__misc__pixfmt.html#ga9e74b43a3433ccfe836814f0a6371aa0).

Comment: Needed to add an additional `d` as `ffmpeg -i input.mp4 '%04d.png'`

Answer (score 20):

If you know exactly which frames to extract, eg 1, 200, 400, 600, 800, 1000, try using:

```
select='eq(n\,1)+eq(n\,200)+eq(n\,400)+eq(n\,600)+eq(n\,800)+eq(n\,1000)' \
       -vsync vfr -q:v 2
```

I'm using this with a pipe to Imagemagick's montage to get 10 frames preview from any videos. Obviously the frame numbers you'll need to figure out using `ffprobe`

```
ffmpeg -i myVideo.mov -vf \
    select='eq(n\,1)+eq(n\,200)+eq(n\,400)+eq(n\,600)+eq(n\,800)+eq(n\,1000)',scale=320:-1 \
    -vsync vfr -q:v 2 -f image2pipe -vcodec ppm - \
  | montage -tile x1 -geometry "1x1+0+0<" -quality 100 -frame 1 - output.png
```

.

**Little explanation:**

1. In ffmpeg expressions `+` stands for OR and `*` for AND
2. `\,` is simply escaping the `,` character
3. Without `-vsync vfr -q:v 2` it doesn't seem to work but I don't know why - anyone?

Comment: `eq(n\,1)` would extract 2nd frame (order starts at 0)

Comment: `-q:v` is an alias for `-qscale:v` (https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/MPEG-4) and controls image quality. `-vsync vfr` is the video sync method (you first need to understand `-vf` which is a filtergraph) . According to the docs `vfr` means `Frames are passed through with their timestamp or dropped so as to prevent 2 frames from having the same timestamp.` *I think* this is to avoid the default option `cfr` as stated here https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html

Answer (score 20):

Output one image every minute, named img001.jpg, img002.jpg, img003.jpg, etc. The %03d dictates that the ordinal number of each output image will be formatted using 3 digits.

```
ffmpeg -i myvideo.avi -vf fps=1/60 img%03d.jpg
```

Change the `fps=1/60` to `fps=1/30` to capture a image every 30 seconds. Similarly if you want to capture a image every 5 seconds then change `fps=1/60` to `fps=1/5`

SOURCE: [https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Create a thumbnail image every X seconds of the video](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Create%20a%20thumbnail%20image%20every%20X%20seconds%20of%20the%20video)

Answer (score 8):

This worked for me

`ffmpeg -i file.mp4 -vf fps=1 %d.jpg`

Comment: This extracts one frame per second, not every frame according to the original video FPS value.

Comment: You can get framerate using `ffprobe -v 0 -of csv=p=0 -select_streams v:0 -show_entries stream=r_frame_rate infile` and they use fps=<value>

Comment: You don't need to specify the fps parameter.

Comment: use `-r 1` instead of `-vf fps=1`

Answer (score 5):

I tried it. 3600 frame in 32 seconds. your method is really slow. You should try this.

```
ffmpeg -i file.mpg -s 240x135 -vf fps=1 %d.jpg
```

Comment: I am trying 

`ffmpeg -i "input URL" -vf fps=1/5 out%d.png`

where the input URL has to be an https link.

Comment: Sure, scaling them to a tiny size makes it faster, but that's not what he asked for.

Answer (score 2):

In my case I need frames at least every second. I used the 'seek to' approach above but wondered if I could parallelize the task.  I used the N processes with FIFO approach here:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/103920/parallelize-a-bash-for-loop/216475#216475

```
open_sem(){
  mkfifo /tmp/pipe-$$
  exec 3<>/tmp/pipe-$$
  rm /tmp/pipe-$$
  local i=$1
  for((;i>0;i--)); do
    printf %s 000 >&3
  done
}
run_with_lock(){
    local x
    read -u 3 -n 3 x && ((0==x)) || exit $x
    (
    "$@" 
    printf '%.3d' $? >&3
    )&
}
N=16
open_sem $N
time for i in {0..39} ; do run_with_lock ffmpeg -ss `echo $i` -i /tmp/input/GOPR1456.MP4  -frames:v 1 /tmp/output/period_down_$i.jpg  & done
```

Essentially I forked the process with & but limited the number of concurrent threads to N.

This improved the 'seek to' approach from 26 seconds to 16 seconds in my case.  The only problem is the main thread does not exit cleanly back to the terminal since stdout gets flooded.

Answer (score 2):

Same as @makeworld's answer but also addresses issues mentioned [here regarding frame count inconsistencies and need for vsync](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54736972/ffmpeg-inconsistent-frame-counts) and [here regarding use of vsync](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70880957/extracting-frames-from-mp4in-ffmpeg-to-jpg-format-produces-error-when-using-vsy):

```
// reliably works for jpg output (and probably png too)
ffmpeg -i rgb.mov -vf setpts=N/FR/TB -vsync 0 ./images/%05d.jpg

// reliably works for png output only
ffmpeg -i rgb.mov -vsync 0 ./images/%05d.png
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `ffmpeg-6.0` on a Win-11 PC, I could not get it to work until I tried:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 frame_%%03d.png
```

Not sure why I needed `%%` rather than the `%` mentioned above.