# How to extract frames from a video with transparency?

Tags: java, ffmpeg, photoshop, xuggler, xuggle

How do I extract frames from a video (.mov Apple ProRes 4444) with the alpha channel?

I need the PNG images so transparency is not lost.

I have 23 videos so I would prefer to automate the process.

Comment: `ffmpeg -i in.mov -vsync 0 in%d.png` gets you the images.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If any reads this in future, this worked for me

```
ffmpeg -i file.mov -r 24/1 output%03d.png
```

**Reference:**

1. Mulvya's comment
2. [Fastest way to extract frames using ffmpeg?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10957412/fastest-way-to-extract-frames-using-ffmpeg)