# Extracting frames from video while recording using ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, raspberry-pi, camera

I am using ffmpeg to record a video using a Raspberry Pi with its camera module.
I would like to run a image classifier on a regular interval for which I need to extract a frame from the stream.

This is the command I currently use for recording:

```
$ ffmpeg -f video4linux2 -input_format h264 -video_size 1280x720 -framerate 30 -i /dev/video0 -vcodec copy -an test.h264
```

[In other threads this command is recommended](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10957412/fastest-way-to-extract-frames-using-ffmpeg):

```
ffmpeg -i file.mpg -r 1/1 $filename%03d.bmp
```

I don't think this is intended to be used with files that are still appended to and I get the error "Cannot use -sseof, duration of test.h264 not known".

Is there any way that ffmpeg allows this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have a Raspberry Pi set up with a camera at the moment to test with, but you should be able to simply append a second output stream to your original command, as follows to get, say, 1 frame/second of BMP images:

```
ffmpeg -f video4linux2 -input_format h264 -video_size 1280x720 -framerate 30 -i /dev/video0 -vcodec copy -an test.h264 -r 1 frame-%03d.bmp
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This is a perfect solution for my needs.