# How to handle DHAV (.dav) video streams?

Tags: c#, wpf, ffmpeg, stream, video-streaming

I have a WPF app where I need to handle `DHAV (.dav)` video stream on runtime from a `Digital Video Recorder (DVR)`. I'm using an SDK that can be found here [Dahua SDK search](https://www.dahuasecurity.com/support/downloadCenter/download-search?keyword=Sdk&us)

```
SDK: General_NetSDK_Eng_Win64_IS_V3.052.0000002.0.R.201103
```

I need to handle every single frame from the video stream, convert it to a `BitmapImage` and then displays it in a `WPF Image control`. Something like: [MJPEG Decoder](https://channel9.msdn.com/coding4fun/articles/MJPEG-Decoder)

The problem is that I can't find any documentation on how to handle that data and the samples from the SDK doesn't show that either, instead they are built with WinForms and they only pass the Window Handle of the PictureBox's control to an exported DLL function and 'magically' shows the video stream:

```
[DllImport(LIBRARYNETSDK)]
public static extern IntPtr CLIENT_RealPlayEx(IntPtr lLoginID, int nChannelID, IntPtr hWnd, EM_RealPlayType rType);
```

> OBS: 'hWnd' param is the Window Handle to display the video in.

The problem with this approach is that I don't have any control over the video stream.

I have tried many FFMPEG wrappers for .NET but they only parse the data if I first write it to disk and only then I can convert it to some type I can handle.

This is the callback function that is called contantly during the application's runtime with the data I need to handle:

```
    private void RealDataCallback(IntPtr lRealHandle, uint dwDataType, IntPtr pBuffer, uint dwBufSize, IntPtr param, IntPtr dwUser)
    {
        switch (dwDataType)
        {
            case 0: // original data
                break;
            case 1: // frame data
                HandleFrameData(lRealHandle, dwDataType, pBuffer, dwBufSize, param, dwUser);
                break;
            case 2: // yuv data
                break;
            case 3: // pcm audio data
                break;
        }
    }

    private void HandleFrameData(IntPtr lRealHandle, uint dwDataType, IntPtr pBuffer, uint dwBufSize, IntPtr param, IntPtr dwUser)
    {
        // The pBuffer parameter format is DHAV (.dav) 
        byte[] buff = new byte[dwBufSize];
        Marshal.Copy(pBuffer, buff, 0, (int)dwBufSize);

        using (var ms = new MemoryStream(buff))
        {
        }
    }
```

#### UPDATE

I'm able to convert the YUV data provided in the callback funcion to RGB but that is not the ideal solution. It would be so much better (and faster) if I can convert the original (.dav) data.

The `RealDataCallback`, in fact, only returns 1 frame per callback, but I don't know how to convert that frame to Bitmap. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You can try to use [YUV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YUV) data supplied to the callback. Converting it to RGB is quite easy.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I was able to convert YUV[] to RGB[] but converting it from RGB[] to Bitmap doesn't seem to be so easy because I'm having some issues in the result of the images... But I'm going to open a separate question for them...

Comment: The best way to mess with video frames in WPF would be with [FFmpeg.Autogen](https://github.com/Ruslan-B/FFmpeg.AutoGen) bindings for FFmpeg. I have already a WPF video player .NET library which includes snapshots that might be a quick solution for you [Flyleaf](https://github.com/SuRGeoNix/Flyleaf)

Comment: Maybe that can help https://www.programmersought.com/article/39157248216/

Comment: Two suggestions: 1) don't allocate your buffer every frame, you'll bring the garbage collector to its knees, and 2) use a YUV->RGB pixel shader to do the conversion, it'll literally be thousands of times faster on even modest hardware.

Comment: @MarkFeldman That was just an example. Like I said, I'm already doing this conversion of YUV > RGB. One problem (which I didn't mention in the post), is that the SDK only provides the YUV data if I pass the display window handle as a parameter to the function that starts the stream. That's why I wanted to handle the original data instead of the YUV. So I'll probably have to convert the .DAV > YUV somehow.

Comment: Ah, ok then. I take it you've already looked at the [ffmpeg decoder code](https://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/dhav_8c_source.html)?

Comment: Not shure if I correctly understand your problem, but FFMPEG is powerful tool. So maybe it will be better to use it as usual system command call? FFMPEG can read stream from input https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45899585/pipe-input-in-to-ffmpeg-stdin So you can pipe `curl` output, for example. And, of course FFMPEG can convert input video to frame images https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10957412/fastest-way-to-extract-frames-using-ffmpeg